# Installing nginx, info.php, connect() failed to open php5-fpm.sock

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu, nginx, rtmp

Attempting to access:

```
mydomain.name/info.php
```

Error Log:

> 2016/01/01 18:23:00 [crit] 15592#0: *1 connect() to unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock failed (13: Permission denied) while
>   connecting to upstream, client: censoredipaddress1, server:
>   censoredipaddress2, request: "GET /info.php HTTP/1.1", upstream:
>   "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock:", host: "censoredipaddress3"

Censored addresses:

1: test home computer ip address

2: ipaddress to nginx VPS

3: domain name

NGinx (installed from source code with RTMP module added)

Customizations: basic_auth, RTMP

```
Ref. 1A: https://obsproject.com/forum/resources/how-to-set-up-your-own-private-rtmp-server-using-nginx.50/
```

Linux EngineX MySQL PHP (on Ubuntu 15 x64)

```
Ref. 2A: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-nginx-mysql-php-lemp-stack-on-ubuntu-14-04
```

<<<  MISC NOTES/COMMENTS  >>>

I noticed that source builds of NGinx, the actual file path to html is /usr/local/nginx/html and folders called "websites_enabled" or the like do not exist (as far as I know).

When using (i did NOT use this to install nginx because it does not allow me to easily add RTMP, If I have to do it this way then please explain how to install RTMP this way)

```
apt-get install nginx
```

the websites_enabled file structure is present and so are the expected /usr/shared and /www directories.

I tried some other fixes which made me include some stuffs like www-data but I am not using www-data (i think that is used when my html file is found in www/)

I'm trying to add PHP to my RTMP streaming capabilities and since I am unable to install RTMP using apt-get install nginx I will need help installing RTMP if I am forced to use apt-get install nginx to be able to use php.

Thank You In Advance!

Comment: Do you have php-fpm installed? Is it set up to listen to the socketfile?

Comment: php-fpm can listen to either a tcp socket, or a socket file. Whatever you have set for that must be the same as nginx is will connect on.

Comment: In my nginx.conf file, under http>server>location> ~ \.php$  (incomplete)

        `location ~ \.php$ {
     try_files $uri =404;#
            root           html;
     fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_pass   unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
            ...
            include        fastcgi_params;
        }`

In my www.conf file under /etc/php5/fpm/pool.d, I have the following line which I believe allows it to listen 
`; Note: This value is mandatory.
listen = /var/run/php5-fpm.sock`

Am I checking the right files and putting the right values? THank You for your help

Comment: That should be correct. You will need to make sure the user configured in php-fpm settings is the same as nginx. ANd that php-fpm is running

Comment: per `ps aux | less` i see that root and www-data is running php-fpm in 3 different PIDs and then it is revealed that nobody is running nginx.

I then changed the user to www-data in my nginx.conf and it works now.

Thank You so much, is there any security issues with changing the user on nginx side?

Comment: Both services don't need to use the same user, both they both need to be able to read the socket file. I don't think you will run into any issues with using the same user.

Comment: I see, thank you for lending me your experience.